# Problem regarding unique solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A unique  solution  to the  differential  equation  $y = x \frac{dy}{dx} - (\frac{dy}{dx})^2$ passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ doesnot exist

then choose the  correct option

$1.$ if $ x_0^2 > 4y_0$

$2.$ if $ x_0^2 = 4y_0$

$3.$ if $ x_0^2 < 4y_0$

$4.$ for any $(x_0 , y_0)$

My attempt  : Here $y = x \frac{dy}{dx} - (\frac{dy}{dx})^2$

Now i put  $x= e^z$ then $z= \log x$

So $y= Dy- D^2y$

$D^2y-Dy -y=0$

so $(D^2-D-1)y=0$

so auxiliary equation will  be $m^2-m-1=0$ ,$m= \frac{1 +_{-}\sqrt - 3}{2}$

so $y= e^{\frac{1}{2}x} (c_1 \cos(\frac{\sqrt - 3}{2} ) + c_2\sin ({\frac{\sqrt - 3}{2}} )x)$

After that im not able  to proceed further

Comment: It is not a second order equation. $D^2y = \frac{d^2y}{d?^2}$ ? ... something has gone desperately wrong! ... The differential equation is of second degree (like a quadratic) so you should expect $2$ solutions ... so you can probably guess which option is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $y=bx-b^2$ is a solution, where
$$
b=\frac{-x_0\pm\sqrt{x_0^2-4y_0}}{2}
$$
This gives us two distinct solutions whenever $x_0^2\neq 4y_0$.  If instead $x_0^2=4y_0$, we can still find a second solution $y=x^2/4$.

Comment: If you're looking for **real** solutions, there are none when $x_0^2 < 4 y_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: First treat the differantial equation as a quadratic in $\frac{dy}{dx}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 -x \frac{dy}{dx} +y=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now plug this into the quadratic formula and ... ?

Answer (score 3):

$$(y')^2-xy'=-y$$
Complete the square:
$$(y')^2-xy'+\frac {x^2} 4 =-y+\frac {x^2} 4 $$
$$(y'-\frac x 2 )^2=-y+\dfrac {x^2} 4 $$
The differential equation reduces to:
$$(z')^2=z$$
Where $z=-y+\dfrac {x^2} 4 $

Now you have to analyse what happens when $z <0,z=0,z>0$